# Hotspot access showing web page

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, hotspot

Sometimes when you are accessing wifi (hotspot) at the cafe or shopping mall, you will be redirect to their webpage. Only then, you can start using the wifi.

How can that be done? Any specific hardware or software needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you attempting to do this at home or at a corporate enviroment. Generally what your looking for is called a captive portal. I'm not sure it is possible in a home enviroment with out a server setup for this. Corporate equipment sometimes have this built in. You'll need to refer to hardwar manual if so.

Basically the run down would be this:
1 Have a dedicated server/router setup up
2 Create the captive portal (instructions vary by software)
3 Make sure router is set to use the server as the default gateway
4 Make sure dhcp is turned off on router

In this setup any client would have to pass through the captive portal to hit the internet.

The physical setup would look similar to this:
Internet -> Modem -> Captive Server -> router -> client

Apparently DD-WRT V23 SP2 has this ability
[Create Your Own Hotspot (Using DD-WRT)](http://www.wi-fiplanet.com/tutorials/print.php/3730746)